# Create base64 string from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, gd

I need to make screenshot from specific DIV in HTML page.
I tried to use this library - http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

```
html2canvas($(".element"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    }
});
```

But it has problems with some CSS stuff ( text-shadow for example ) and some texts are not looking good. and also picture seems a bit blurry.

Is there any other solution?

My DIV contains background picture, and texts on it.
I considered using PHP GD library to open that background image and position texts on it, but there comes the text-shadow again, which i don't know how to do.

The CSS which makes text-shadow is like this:

```
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

Comment: When you say the picture "seems a bit blurry" - you are converting it to jpeg without specifying the the quality.  Have you tried `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);`? - quality parameter ranges from 0 to 1, not sure what the default is but it will be something near 0.8 (lossy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 Canvas has support for text shadowing http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/

The library you're using probably just doesn't support it properly or it isn't searching for the CSS.

If you share the DIV markup and CSS a hardcoded (specific) solution could probably be reached.

---

Another way to go is using a screen shot web service like http://browsershots.org

You would create a minimal HTML file that just contains the CSS and the DIV you want and save it (with PHP) to your web directory. You'd then pass that url to the web service and get an image (screen shot) in response.

Comment: Maybe i will try to recreate that DIV on canvas myself and then parse it to .toDataURL();

Comment: I finally made it a bit different way.

I made custom canvas and filled it with data which i got from AJAX.
Canvas supports all shading and stuff.

    $('#bigCard').html($('<canvas id="anniversary" width="496" height="222"></canvas>'));
    var canvas = $("#anniversary")[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'gifts/img/bigcard/bigCard100.png';
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    //here i put all the texts on picture

Comment: @user1199899 - glad you got to a solution

Answer (score 1):

html2canvas doesn't really take an actual screenshot, but recreates the look of the html element using canvas. That is why it doesn't look exaclty right (the shadow etc.).

The *blurriness* is most likely due to you saving the image as a jpeg, try png instead:

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this a few months ago. I used this library :

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

It's easy to use and did the job.
I hope it helps.